# What happens if you don't malloc but instead return using memory address in C?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

**Look at the second edit part.**

I'm beginner of C (since I almost always use Python). So my question is (I can say) simple about malloc and memory...

```
// where the built-in malloc declared
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* data = malloc(13); // with standard malloc
}
```

Let say I don't want to use `stdlib.h` and instead I make my own code for malloc which return ONLY the memory address in a file called `memory.h`

```
void* malloc(int size) {
    return (__malloc_memory += size);
}
```

This function `malloc` returns the address, where `__malloc_memory` is basically 6487580 [__malloc_memory is basically memory address] (tested by declaring some stuff). **So, it is okay to do like this? If not, then why?**

```
// my declaration of new malloc
#include <memory.h>

int main() {
   char* data = malloc(14); // This is the new defined malloc, not the built-in one

   data[0] = 'H';
   // some stuff
   data[12] = '!';
   data[13] = '\0'; // Null terminate

   printf("%s", data);
}
```

Output

```
Hello, world!
```

**The output will return the same everytime.**

**EDIT 1:**

```
// memory.h
static int __malloc_memory = 6487580;

void* malloc(int size) {
    return (__malloc_memory += size);
}
```

And `main.c`

```
int main() {
    double* name = (char*)malloc(1);
    
    name[0] = 3.4555;
    
    printf("%lf", name[0]);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
3.455500
```

**EDIT 2:**

This question sucks. Now I understand what I made is a very basic mistake, since now I understand how an Operating System work (and of course how to make one using Assembly, but not fully).
I will not delete this question, since that is very disrespectful.
[And why the heck I cast *malloc* [in C]...? For what I know, I never do that.]
[Now (as per 07-07-2021), I would call myself a C intermediate (not expert yet).]

Comment: `where __malloc_memory is basically 6487580 (tested by declaring some stuff)` needs some further explanation.

Comment: What is `__malloc_memory `? _"This will return the same everytime"_. Return what? The question is very unclear. What do you expect? Show a [mcve]

Comment: How will you implement `free()`? For a beginner to C, I recommend using the standard library functions.

Comment: Sorry, I edited some stuff...

Comment: The algorithm will create unaligned memory blocks. And `double* name = (char*)malloc(1);` will need more than 1 byte.

Comment: `static int __malloc_memory = 6487580;` : this is just some arbitrary memory location. Writing to it is undefined behaviour which can be anything from "apparently working fine" to "program behaving very strangely" or "program crashing".

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm trying to understand how ```malloc``` and ```free``` works. So if I understand, I don't need to use ```stdlib.h``` and create my own custom ```malloc```

Comment: `static int __malloc_memory = 6487580;` and `return __malloc_memory` make no sense. `__malloc_memory` is not memory, it's a number.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Can you please explain me why?

Comment: Don't try to create your own `malloc` before you're not perfectly current with pointers. And even then: `malloc` is a highly complex function.

Comment: @FaranAiki what makes you think you can write to memory address `6487580`?

Comment: Unless you are working on embedded, without an OS, this is entirely the wrong way to go.

Comment: @Jabberwocky at ```main``` I tested by declaring ```int t = 14244;``` and when I check the memory address, I got that value but lower (approx. 6487572) , then I declare two variable at ```main``` and what I got is lower basically a substraction from the previous declaration (approx. 6487568), and I declare three times I still got the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, thanks for pointing that out, I forgot about that. But then how do you do it without an OS (I seems can't access ```stdlib.h```)?

Comment: By standing on the shoulders of others and seeing how they do it. One solution I have seen is to have lists of available memory blocks of different sized powers of two, and to allocate, split or merge them as the memory manager see fit. All you are doing is taking a random location, and drawing from it like a stack, with no regard for memory alignment. You cannot solve this with a one-line function.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not sure if memory alignement is the main problem here.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Jabberwocky : if you don't have an OS, you can still use malloc() out of the box if your standard library has it own memory allocator.

Comment: Assuming, `__malloc_memory` really is pointing to some memory block for allocation (which you really should think about again), and also assuming that you only want a malloc-only system without any option to free the memory, there is another issue: You first increase the address and then return the new value. This is wrong. You need to return the old value and then increase.

Comment: @Gerhardh "This is wrong. You need to return the old value and then increase", I mean why? Why should I return the old value and then increase it?

Comment: You might draw some picture where you memory blocks are. If you start at `__malloc_memory` and increase it by `size1` before returning the value the caller will get `__malloc_memory+size1` and use it up to `__malloc_memory+2*size1-1`. This means, the first `size` bytes are unused and the next `size` bytes are used instead. If you then call again with `size2` which might be smaller than `size1` you will return an address within the range used by first caller. You have to idea how many bytes after `__malloc_memory` are used by the previous caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you want to allocate memory, but not with `malloc()`, but your own way. Fine. There are many things in play here, but I will try not to leave out or include too much.

When your program starts (when enters `main()`) function it already has some memory to work with. How come? When OS creates a new process it allocates a bit of memory for it. How much is needed can be figured out from the executable file which consists of several parts: code (`.text` segment), static data, etc. Now you're left on your own to allocate memory if you need it.

Well, not really. Program doesn't really start with `main()`. If you put a break at the start of `main()` and run your program in debugger you will see that you are not at the top (or bottom, depending on representation) of the stack. Some things were called before. One of those things is initialization of `libc` and very likely that has already done some allocating using `malloc()` and other means.

When you figured out that using `6487580 == 0x62fe1c` was OK you just managed to find a location that was mapped to your process and very likely allocated by someone else. C standard library is capable of many things and it is very possible that by using this location, while corrupting something, you stepped on a part that you will not be using in your program, so things will seem just fine. In a way they are, but your approach is neither very portable (on a different OS, or even with a different compiler things would not be OK).

But I get your point -- you want to do your own thing. Ultimately, if `libc` can, why not you, right?

Here is one way you could do it bypassing `libc`: use [sbrk()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html).

```c
static const unsigned int my_total_needs = 100;
static void *__malloc_memory = sbrk(my_total_needs);
if ( __malloc_memory == (void *)-1 )
    perror("Couldn't allocate memory.\n");
else {
    /* Do your thing. */
}
```

You asked OS for 100 bytes and if you got them then it is up to you to do with them as you please. You can now write your own `malloc()` that will use smaller c hunks out of these 100 bytes to give to whoever calls it. You can also write your own `free()` that will mark no longer needed chunks as available. Basically, you will write your own memory manager that will manage those 100 bytes. If you need more you can either ask for more at the start or call `sbrk()` again and ask for increase.

This is fun exercise, but good luck doing it better than experts. `libc` and other libraries are optimized for *regular use* which means that if you have a very special case you can maybe do better.

Comment: Thank you, I will learn more about memory :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know the reason, avoid playing with *magic* addresses. So this terrible code:

```
// memory.h
static int __malloc_memory = 6487580;

void* malloc(int size) {
    return (__malloc_memory += size);
}
```

When you use a *magic* address, you should **always** add a comment explaining where it came from (physical io port in real or kernel mode, etc.)

But in the old times where the OS did not know about virtual memory or multi-processing, it was common to use a pre-allocated compile-time defined memory zone as a *local heap* and allocate from there. If you want to learn about the allocation internal details, you can try something like that:

```
HEAPSIZE = 65536;
char heap[HEAPSIZE];
char *cur_heap = heap;

char *malloc(int size) {
    char *ret = cur_heap;

    if (cur_heap + size > heap + HEAPSIZE) { // no more memory to allocate
        return NULL;
    }
    cur_heap += size;
    return ret;
}
```

From that point you will soon realize that with such a simple `malloc` there is no way to free anything, and next that free blocks should be managed in a list or some other *container* structure. If you reach that point, and before trying to invent an oval wheel when round wheels exist, you should have a look to the sources of malloc in any C library implementation. And after you will have builded a functional `malloc` `free` pair, you will have learned a lot...

---

BTW: 65535 was the size of a segment for the old 80x86 architectures...

Comment: Thanks :) actually I used ```6487580``` because it's greater than the first declared memory address.

Comment: @FaranAiki: that means that you do not know what lies at that address, and using it the way you do invokes Undefined Behaviour. Said differently after writing something at a memory you do not directly control, anything can happen from obtaining the expected result to an immediate application crash, with anything in the middle possible like a crash in an unrelated piece of code, or non consistent results...

Comment: You are right. I tested at Online Compiler and then I got SIGSEGV.

Comment: @FaranAiki: you were just (un)lucky not to experience it before ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I guess when I'm trying to understand I think I should compile it to online compilers, gcc, and other OS as well :)